# Swift 4 Objective-C Runtime and casting to NSObjectProtocol

Tags: swift, foundation, objective-c-runtime, swift4

In Swift 3, I had a snipped of code that called into Objective-C runtime to check if a certain class is present.

```
guard let managerClass = NSClassFromString("ASIdentifierManager") as? NSObjectProtocol else {
    return nil
}
```

This returns `AnyClass` instance and it is castable to `NSObjectProtocol` - so I could call methods like `responds` and `perform` to work with selectors.

In Swift 4, this still works at runtime, but will emit a warning:

> Cast from 'AnyClass?' (aka 'Optional') to unrelated type 'NSObjectProtocol' always fails

Oddly it still works, but I am worried a certain Swift version will kill the code.

**What is the proper way to get rid of this warning? To what should I cast the object, to be able to perform selectors on it dynamically?**

Comment: I think you should cast to `NSObjectProtocol.Type`.

Comment: Incorrect, as I am not interested in `NSObjectProtocol.Type`, but rather it is an instance of `NSObjectProtocol`.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you need to cast from `AnyObject.Type` to `AnyObject` first to convince the compiler that you're talking about an instance (albeit an instance of a metaclass, as you know):

```
    guard
        let klass = NSClassFromString("ASIdentifierManager"),
        let managerClass = klass as AnyObject as? NSObjectProtocol else
    {
        return nil
    }
```

I'm not sure whether this should be considered a compiler bug or not. I'd bet not, and that there's some Swiftian reason that `NSObjectProtocol` does not apply to ObjC type objects when in a Swift context.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast to `NSObjectProtocol.Type`:

```
guard let managerClass = NSClassFromString("ASIdentifierManager") as? NSObjectProtocol.Type else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. While you can do this cast without the warning, you can no longer use `responds` and `perform` methods, as this is a type, not an instance anymore.

Comment: This is correct. `NSClassFromString` <- returns `class` not `an instance`. If you want instance you have to create it.

Comment: In Objective-C type class also is an instance of `class` class. Each class instance has a meta class. So it is incorrect. I know it is confusing, but it is effectively how Objective-C runtime works.

Comment: @Legoless You want to call `class method` through `perform selector`?

Comment: Exactly, yes! The code I had worked in Swift 3 and is semantically correct. The code actually still works, but will emit warning described in the question.

Comment: Did you actually try my code? It should work I guess

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, because there's no way to call any Objective-C runtime methods on that meta type.